# How do you filter all elements out of an array which are just variants of an existing element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filter

I have the following array and want to filter out all the variants of an existing element:

```
let array = ["A15", "A16", "A15.1", "A16.1"]
```

After the filter, I want to have an array that does not include *A15.1* since it is a variant of *A15*

```
filtered_array = ["A15", "A16"]
```

A variant of an existing element should be every element that contains part of another existing element but also deviates from it.
Since for example *A15.1* also contains *A15*, it should therefore be filtered out.
I also already tried to filter out every element that contains a part that already exists in the array.

How do I filter those out?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is a variant? what if the order is different, which one should be in the result set? what have you tried?

Comment: Regarding all the provided approaches, are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

Imperative solution:

```
let array = ["A15", "A16", "A15.1"]
let filtered_array = []
for (const element of array) {
  const foundElement = filtered_array.find((existingElement) => element.startsWith(existingElement))
  if (!foundElement) {
    filtered_array.push(element)
  }
}
```

Depending on what you mean by "variant", you may need to change the function within the find. For example:

```
const isVariant = (original, variant) => variant.startsWith(original)

let array = ["A15", "A16", "A15.1"]
let filtered_array = []
for (const element of array) {
  const foundElement = filtered_array.find((existingElement) => isVariant(existingElement, element))
  if (!foundElement) {
    filtered_array.push(element)
  }
}
```

EDIT: Updated to use `startsWith` instead of `contains`.

Comment: @JoaquimdSouza ... for an array like `["A15.1", "A15.1.1", "ab-A16.3", "A16", "A15", "xy-A16.3.1", "A16.3"]` the suggested solution(s both) compute(s) `["A15.1", "ab-A16.3", "A16", "A15"]` whereas the expected result is `["A16", "A15"]`.

Comment: True. Perhaps `startsWith` is a better choice than `contains`

Comment: @JoaquimdSouza ... do you actually test your code before posting it as solution? The result still is not as expected. The problem was not the `includes` based `isVariant` implementation which btw. now will cause trouble due to using `startsWith`.

Comment: I think it depends on what the OP means by "variant", and whether the OP cares about array order. I think you are making assumptions on what the inputs and expected outputs are, but we don't have this information (yet)

Comment: @ElFuerst ... please clarify the acceptance criteria.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getNormalizedStringValues(arr) {
  // transform e.g.
  // ... ["A15.1", "A15.1.1", "ab-A16.3", "A16", "A15", "xy-A16.3.1", "A16.3"]
  // into a sorted copy of itself like
  // ... ["A16", "A15", "A15.1", "A16.3", "A15.1.1", "ab-A16.3", "xy-A16.3.1"]
  arr = [...arr].sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);

  let leftValue, rightValue;
  let count, idx = -1;

  // iterate the array from its left side ...
  while (++idx < (count = arr.length)) {
    // ... with a current `leftValue`.
    leftValue = arr[idx];

    // iterate the array from its right side with a current `rightValue` ...
    // ... until either a left/right value match or running out of a value.
    while ((rightValue = arr[--count]) && (leftValue !== rightValue)) {
      if (rightValue.includes(leftValue)) {

        // mutate/shrink/condense the currently processed array
        // from its right side by constantly removing
        // item variant after item variant.
        arr.splice(count, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
const sampleList = ["A15.1", "A15.1.1", "ab-A16.3", "A16", "A15", "xy-A16.3.1", "A16.3"];

console.log(
  'getNormalizedStringValues(sampleList) ...',
  getNormalizedStringValues(sampleList)
);
console.log('sampleList ...', sampleList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```